# function attribute returns_twice

Tags: c++, c, function, function-attributes

I just was looking up funciton attributes for gcc 
(http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)
and came across the `returns_twice` attribute.

And I am absolutely clueless in what case a function can return twice... I looked up quickly the mentioned `vfork()` and `setjmp()` but continue without an idea how an applicable scenario looks like - anyone of you used it or can explain a bit?

Comment: Look up `vfork()` and `setjmp()` slowly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `setjmp` function is analogous to creating a *label* (in the `goto` sense), as such you will first return from `setjmp` when you set the label, and then each time that you actually jump to it.

If it seems weird, rest assured, you should not be using `setjmp` in your daily programming. Or actually... you should probably not be using it *at all*. It is a very low-level command that break the expected execution flow (much like `goto`) and, especially in C++, most of the invariants you could expect.

Answer (score 5):

When you call `setjmp`, it establishes that as a return point, then execution continues at the code immediately following the `setjmp` call.

At some point later in the code, calling `longjmp` (with the jump buffer initialized by the previous call to `setjmp`) returns execution to start from that same point again (i.e., the code immediately following the call the `setjmp`).

Therefore, the original call returns normally, then at arbitrary later times, execution returns (or at least *may* return) to the same point again.

The attribute simply warns the compiler of that fact.